# How do I diagnose ABS problem with Toyota CE110 - 1996

Tags: toyota, abs

The ABS indicator is illuminating in this car, according to the mechanic the ABS ECU is fried.

I have tried rotating few reconditioned ABS ECUs with the same problem. So I'm not very sure if the ECU is to blame, and purchasing a brand new ECU will cost $1000+. So before going for that option I would like to make sure if the ECU is the problem.

Is there a way to diagnose this?

Comment: Did you ask your mechanic *why* he thinks the ABS ECU is fried? They seem to get changed regularly if the mechanic can't determine the fault, but often it's sensors at fault, not the ECU itself.

Comment: He said it's the usual case, even though he has this scanning equipment he said that it's fried and it needs to be replaced.

Comment: The part that makes me think this might not be the case is that you said you already swapped in a couple of other ABS ECUs and they didn't work either. The law of averages suggests that it's fairly unlikely that you end up only with dead ones, especially if they've been reconditioned by someone who knows what they're doing. I think you have an electrical fault, but not necessarily inside the ECU. I'd check for power at the ECU first and then go hunting for a broken wire.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to get your own hand held and diagnose this yourself. You can pick up various ones for $30-$2000 (if you really want to pay that much). The lower costing ones are Bluetooth designed to work with your smartphone.

I too am doubting the voracity of this problem being a fried ABS ECU, mainly because in some vehicles, a brake light can cause the ABS light to come on. Until you get the codes from the ABS read, you are really in the dark about it. Getting an OBDII scantool with ABS and SRS diagnostic features is a must for any DIY toolbox.